# Why does the bytestring-show package install using Stack fail?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

It installs just fine with `cabal install bytestring-show`. Here is the log:

```
Configuring bytestring-show-0.3.5.6...
Building bytestring-show-0.3.5.6...
Preprocessing library bytestring-show-0.3.5.6...
[1 of 6] Compiling Text.Show.ByteString.Util ( Text\Show\ByteString\Util.hs, .stack-work\dist\b7fec021\build\Text\Show\ByteString\Util.o )
[2 of 6] Compiling Text.Show.ByteString.Char ( Text\Show\ByteString\Char.hs, .stack-work\dist\b7fec021\build\Text\Show\ByteString\Char.o )
[3 of 6] Compiling Text.Show.ByteString.Int ( Text\Show\ByteString\Int.hs, .stack-work\dist\b7fec021\build\Text\Show\ByteString\Int.o )
[4 of 6] Compiling Text.Show.ByteString.Integer ( Text\Show\ByteString\Integer.hs, .stack-work\dist\b7fec021\build\Text\Show\ByteString\Integer.o )

Text\Show\ByteString\Integer.hs:27:1: warning: [-Wunused-imports]
    The import of `GHC.Num' is redundant
      except perhaps to import instances from `GHC.Num'
    To import instances alone, use: import GHC.Num()
[5 of 6] Compiling Text.Show.ByteString.Float ( Text\Show\ByteString\Float.hs, .stack-work\dist\b7fec021\build\Text\Show\ByteString\Float.o )
[6 of 6] Compiling Text.Show.ByteString ( Text\Show\ByteString.hs, .stack-work\dist\b7fec021\build\Text\Show\ByteString.o )

Text\Show\ByteString.hs:205:10: warning: [-Wredundant-constraints]
    * Redundant constraint: Integral a
    * In the instance declaration for `Show (Ratio a)'

Text\Show\ByteString.hs:209:10: warning: [-Wredundant-constraints]
    * Redundant constraint: RealFloat a
    * In the instance declaration for `Show (Complex a)'
Installing library in C:\Users\Marko\Documents\Visual Studio
2015\Projects\Multi-armed Bandit Experiments\Spiral V5
Haskell\.stack-work\install\93264ba9\lib\x86_64-windows-ghc-8.0.1\bytestring-show-0.3.5.6-BjSy8lPQnxSIztPkxWzSlH
copyFile: does not exist (The system cannot find the path specified.)
```

At first the error on the last line was `access denied` so I did the above with the administrator access and it complains that it cannot find the path specified.

I put `extra-deps: [bytestring-show-0.3.5.6]` into the yaml file and added `bytestring-show` as build dependency into the cabal file.

I also tried upgrading stack and am getting this error:

```
C:\>stack upgrade
Updating package index Hackage (mirrored at https://github.com/commercialhaskell                                                                                Fetching package index ...remote: Counting objects: 1, done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Fetched package index.
Populated index cache.
Compiler version mismatched, found ghc-8.0.1 (x86_64), but expected minor version match with ghc-7.10.3 (x86_64) (based on resolver setting in C:\Users\Marko\AppData\Local\Temp\stack-upgrade8368\stack-1.3.2\stack.yaml).
Try rerunning with --install-ghc to install the correct GHC into C:\Users\Marko\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\
```

I just installed Haskell platform yesterday, but I had an earlier version from a few month ago installed so maybe it did not get cleaned up properly.

I am not sure what to do here.

Comment: I don't have any experience with Haskell on Windows, and can't reproduce the issue on Linux, but here are two hunches: either the spaces in the path, or the length of the path might be a problem. Can you try a shorter path that doesn't contain any spaces?

Comment: I tried as you suggested and by accident figured out what the problem is. It seems I should not have deleted the dependency on `simple` in the cabal file even though it seemed redundant. That was it. Thanks.

Comment: In addition, the project name is sensitive to the name of the folder it is in and possibly its location, which is also something that I should not have messed with.

Comment: ...In addition, it seems you were right about spaces as well.

Comment: That interaction with the removal of another dependency sounds strange. If you think that `stack` misbehaves in any way, please consider filing a bug report! :)

Comment: I'll do it tomorrow as the thing with whitespaces is stopping me from putting project with the rest of the repo. I ran into something like this when I first tried the Atom Repl plugin. It is like I am the only Haskell user on Windows. :)

Comment: Here is [the report](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2936). As it turns out, there is a build corruption bug. It has nothing to do with whitespaces.